# Specify decimal places for all placeholders with String.Format

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

With [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) syntax, I know that I can format `double`s with a set number of decimal places as follows:

```
String.Format("{0:F8}", 0.123456789);
```

That's fine for most cases, but I'm writing a function in which the calling function should specify a format string. The format string specifies the way that the function interacts with an external program. High precision is required, and thus all `double`s need to be formatted to 8 decimal places. In the interest of separating interface from implementation, I can't expect calling functions to understand the need for the precision, and thus can't expect the format string to include the decimal specifier in the format string.

My current best option is to just modify the format string with a regex. Is there a cleaner way to specify that all `double`s formatted by `String.Format` should have this precision?

---

The function is typically called with the following two parameters:

- A format string, for example `"new Generator.{0} bus1={1} phases=3 model=1 status=fixed kV={2} Vminpu=0.5 Vmaxpu=2kW=0 kvAR={3}"`
- A lambda function that maps an internally obtained object to an array of values for the format string.

Comment: Would the callers use just `F` as format string? The current culture holds a number format where some "default" numbers of decimals are specified. _Edit:_ Quote from the doc, _If the precision specifier is omitted, the current `NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits` property supplies the numeric precision._

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks for that. It's likely that the user will only specify the `{0}`, however.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the scenario completely. Could you please give some more code where we can see what **types** of parameters are passed in. Do the user supply a `double` variable together with the magical string `"{0}"`, or what?

Comment: Updated the question. @JeppeStigNielsen thanks for your questions - they've made me realise the design pattern I'm using might be less-than-ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create an extension method for `double`? It should return the string-converted `double` -- formatted with the precision you want (8 decimal places). So that the calling function can just specify a format string.. nothing else.. no need to specify a numeric precision.

Something like:

```
static string ToPreciseString(this double data)
{
    return String.Format("{0:F8}", data);
}
```

So the function you are creating can just be something like:

```
void MyFunction(string stringFormatWithoutPrecision)
{
    double anyDoubleValue; //i dont know where you get the double data from
    string formattedData = String.Format(stringFormatWithoutPrecision, anyDoubleValue.ToPreciseString());
}
```